# Android E-Mail App: How to limit contacts for new email to contacts of specific account?

Tags: email, contact-groups

I am using the native E-Mail App on an Samsung Galaxy 4 Mini with Android 4.2.2. I use the app to read and send business email with my outlook exchange account. For other emails I use gmail app. When composing a new email in E-Mail app and start typing in the "To:" field suggestions of email addresses occur. So far so good. But:
Most of the suggested addresses are old gmail contacts or otherwise private contacts. This expands the list to a near unusable length. Is there a way to tell the app to only list contacts from the account entered in the E-Mail App?
If not, can I store addresses I often use in a favorites list or such (I was hoping this would happen by itself over time, but after month of use the app still does not remember anything of the sort)?
Please when suggesting a solution also understand that I do not what to general limit contact sync on my phone to the outlook contacts.

Any tips would be appreciated.
Monica